# Is there any guarantee that multiple type_index instances for a type will compare equal?

Tags: c++, qnx

I have some code which expects `type_index` instances for a particular type created in a shared library and instances created in an executable (for the same particular type) to compare equal.

However, I have encountered a case where this does not work on QNX 7:

```
// idxlib.h

#include <typeindex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef BUILD_LIB
#define LIB_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#define LIB_EXPORT 
#endif

template <typename T>
class Templ 
{
};

class LIB_EXPORT LibType 
{
public:
    LibType();

    template <typename T=int>
    void templateMethod(int arg = 0) const
    {

#ifndef REMOVE_INSTANTIATION
        if (arg == 42)
        {
            // arg is never 42. This code path is not taken, but it instantiates the template
            templateMethod();
        }
#endif

        if (mti == std::type_index(typeid(Templ<int>)))
            std::cout << "Type indexes the same" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Type indexes NOT the same" << std::endl;
    }

    void normalMethod();

protected:
    std::type_index mti;
};
```

```
// idxlib.cpp

#include "idxlib.h"

LibType::LibType() : mti(std::type_index(typeid(Templ<int>))) {}

void LibType::normalMethod()
{
    templateMethod();
}
```

```
// sharedidx.cpp

#include "idxlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LibType lt;

    if (argc == 65)
        // argc is not 65, so don't call it, just instantiate it
        lt.templateMethod();
    lt.normalMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Build, scp and run:

```
QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -fPIC -o idxlib.cpp.o -c idxlib.cpp -DBUILD_LIB -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -shared  -o libidx.so idxlib.cpp.o 
QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -o sharedidx libidx.so  sharedidx.cpp

scp -i ~/qnxinstall/id_rsa_qnx sharedidx libidx.so qnxuser@${QNXBOX}:/home/qnxuser/test

echo
echo "comparison fails:"
ssh -i ~/qnxinstall/id_rsa_qnx -t qnxuser@${QNXBOX} "cd /home/qnxuser/test && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/qnxuser/test ./sharedidx"

QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -shared -fPIC -o idxlib.cpp.o -c idxlib.cpp -DREMOVE_INSTANTIATION -DBUILD_LIB -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -shared  -o libidx.so idxlib.cpp.o 
QCC -Vgcc_ntox86_64 -g -o sharedidx libidx.so -DREMOVE_INSTANTIATION sharedidx.cpp -fvisibility=hidden  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden

scp -i ~/qnxinstall/id_rsa_qnx sharedidx libidx.so qnxuser@${QNXBOX}:/home/qnxuser/test

echo
echo "comparison works:"
ssh -i ~/qnxinstall/id_rsa_qnx -t qnxuser@${QNXBOX} "cd /home/qnxuser/test && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/qnxuser/test ./sharedidx"
```

Output:

```
Type indexes NOT the same
Type indexes the same
```

So, the type_index comparison fails when there is a template instantiation which contains a template instantiation of itself.

Is it a bug in QNX 7, or is my expectation (that it should ever work) wrong?

Is this code relying on implementation-defined behavior? Or undefined behavior?

QNX 7 QCC compiler is based on GCC 5.4 and uses a standard library based on libc++ from the same era. I have tested GCC 5.4 (and clang with libc++ and libstdc++) on Linux and I do not get the same behavior. I have also tried with and without `_LIBCPP_NONUNIQUE_RTTI_BIT` defined.

So, I'm assuming this is a result of the linker rather than the compiler. Could that be true?

Are the GCC compilers just "too helpful" in making this work on Linux across shared library boundaries?

Comment: You need to make sure the type's rtti info is exported from one of the shared libraries so that each library doesn't end up with its own copy

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496643/using-clang-fvisibility-hidden-and-typeinfo-and-type-erasure for example

Answer (score 1):

I would never assume that RTTI works correctly on an embedded systems targeting toolchain. It might be *supposed* to work correctly, but almost nobody enables RTTI nor exceptions for embedded systems, so it'll get zero testing nor attention from support.

I'd suggest that you use a library based RTTI emulation, such as https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html which works on systems without RTTI, and is also fully deterministic and bounded in space and time unlike language RTTI.